# Is there a way to reliably measure how long an external file takes to be created?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, file-io

At work I have come across an error where a service I am running times out when waiting for a file to be created. What I am wondering is if there is a way for the to measure using an external application how long files take to be completely created in a particular directory.

The accuracy does not need to be perfect, but rather a general indication on how quickly files are being generated. I was thinking that I could poll a directory for new files, record their size on first discovery and wait until the file size stops growing, but this seems cumbersome and far from an ideal and accurate solution.

Suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Now here is finally a situation where the many events a [`FileSystemWatcher`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) generates for a single "thing" happening to file may be useful. Note accuracy is going to be tough unless it really takes a long time. Also, it may not be correlated just to the size of the file, and if there is correlation, it is likely it is not linear.

Comment: Times out? As in, taking tens of seconds to create a file? That's highly suspicious. Are you sure you're releasing all the resources safely etc.? The code where you create the file (and dispose of it) would also be useful, you might want to add it to your question.

Comment: There is no way to get a notification or event that reliably tells you that a process closed the file.  You need to periodically try by opening the file with FileShare.Read.  Which will fail as long as a process is still writing to the file.

Comment: @Luaan I don't believe that it is an issue with the services but rather the network as the services have been used for years without issue. I do believe that it is a network problem however it is challenging to prove it as there does not seem to be any visible network problems

Comment: Should be rather easy to prove - make a clone of the service, and have it run (1) over network, (2) locally. If the problem goes away when the service works with local files, network is to blame (although it might still mean a major redesign for you if the network issues are hard to fix :)). Note that I've been working with file-based distributed systems for a while now, and on a completely saturated network I still didn't have any problems with `File.Create`. Perhaps the target directory is too large? Or your domain server is in trouble? Hard to tell.

Comment: @Luaan local services use the same file process so it does seem highly likely that network is the problem, at any rate I increased out timeout/wait period and the issue seems to have disappeared for now.